# Detect when UIView/UILabel redraws itself?

Tags: ios, uiview, calendar, uilabel

I have an app that fetches calendar events and displays data to the user. I'm getting some weird behavior when trying to update my labels.

I can fetch the calendar data just fine but when that gets done, my problem is that according to `NSLog` my `label.text` property has already changed, but it's another 4-8 seconds before the view gets redrawn.

Therefore, I'm trying to detect when the label gets redrawn, not when it's `.text` property changes so I can hide a progress view at the same time the data is populated in the labels.

**I have already tried `setNeedsDisplay` and `setNeedsLayout` on `self.view` and the labels themselves. *after* the `.text` property of the labels has changed  - doesn't work.**

So unless I'm completely missing something about using setNeedsDisplay (which I understand only updates on the next redraw anyway), my question is, how do I detect when the `UILabel` and/or the `UIView` redraws itself?

How my app is setup:

[image]

I've been stuck on this for about 3 weeks.

Comment: It shouldn't take 4-8 seconds to refresh the label unless you are either blocking the main thread for that long or possibly if you are not setting the .text value on the main thread.

Comment: My singleton that does the fetching has a delegate that calls `[mainViewController updateLabels];` Is that "outside" of tha main thread using a delegate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure `setNeedsDisplay` is being called on the main thread, using [`performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSObject), for example:

```
[view performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) 
                       withObject:nil 
                    waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Comment: can you clarify? How do I specifically call it on the main thread?

Comment: My singleton was calling `[mainViewController updateLabels];`. I made a new method for my singleton to call: `[mainViewController refreshLabels];` in which I used `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateLabels) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];` and it worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: Note that you really don't need to call `setNeedsDisplay` at all.  Just making sure that you are updating the label on the main thread will be enough in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Quote apple develop document :

> The view is not actually redrawn until the next drawing cycle, at which point all invalidated views are updated.

maybe your main thread are blocking by other things , such as deal with many complex calculations

eg:

```
- (void)testMethod
{
    myLabel.mytext = @"aaaa";
    [myLabel setNeedsDisplay];
    // some complex calculations
    // the quickest ,  it will run finish the method then redraw.
}
```